# Unable to import pytables with intelpython

Tags: python, pytables

wonder if anyone has tried IntelPython with anaconda. i created an environment as in url link
[Intel Python](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/how-to-install-the-python-version-of-intel-daal-in-linux)

however, when i try to import pytables, i get: -

```
(intelpython) dc@dcpctw:/opt/anaconda3/bin$ python
Python 3.5.3 |Intel Corporation| (default, Apr 27 2017, 18:08:47) 
[GCC 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Intel(R) Distribution for Python is brought to you by Intel Corporation.
Please check out: https://software.intel.com/en-us/python-distribution
>>> import tables
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'tables'
```

Which is strange because i  have it running under the non-intel python environment, so i tried checking if pytables was installed under the intelpython environment

```
(intelpython) dc@dcpctw:/opt/anaconda3/bin$ sudo ./conda upgrade pytables
Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: .

# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at /opt/anaconda3:
#
pytables                  3.3.0           np112py35_intel_2  [intel]  intel
(intelpython) dc@dcpctw:/opt/anaconda3/bin$
```

So its installed in the environment and should work, any help? thanks

Comment: which python version you are using?

Comment: Try without `sudo` and the environment `conda`: `conda upgrade pytables`.

Comment: i have always done conda with sudo because its in the /opt/ directory. but if i am to do it anyway, i get  PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix.
for any conda operation

Comment: Than do `conda install pytables` and see if you can import it.

Comment: its already installed.

Answer (score 0):

You are running the python executable from `/opt/anaconda/bin` but you have an activated environment of `(intelpython)`. Change to a different directory, e.g., `~`, make sure the first `python` on your `PATH` is `/opt/anaconda3/envs/intelpython/bin/python`, and try the import again.